Highlight text that contains some citation
I'm trying to add some new citations in my article. Im using the following command:
"some citations in this fields are \hl{e.g., \cite{abc2020}, \cite{def2021}, among others}."
However, the above line of code is generating error and the citations are not getting highlighted. Please let me know how to fix this so that I can get the entire text written inside the \hl{} highlighted.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide your full code as MWE, i.e., from \documentclass to \end{document}

From the duplicate: \hl{A statement \mbox{\cite{abc2020}}} should work.
